# I'm having trouble implementing the download tag in my <a> for the download of my file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, csv, stringbuilder

I have this program that has a C# controller that uses `StringBuilder` to write to a CSV file which would be downloaded when clicked.

Here's my C# function:

```
public ActionResult GenerateCSV()
{
   StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
   csvContent.AppendLine("Hello, World");
   string fileName = "CSVTest.csv";
   byte[] csvData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());
   return File(csvData, "text/csv", fileName);
   
}
```

The  tag in my html:

```
<a href ="/MyAccount/GenerateCSV" download ="Report.csv" class="btn btn-primary">Generate &raquo;</a>
```

The issue I'm having right now is when I click on `Generate`, instead of having whatever data I have in my `StringBuilder` which I return, there's a bunch of random html code being written to my code, and I assume the issue is with returning `File`. If anyone could help me out with an alternate way of returning the data so it gets picked up by the `<a>` tag it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see that you tagged this question with `StringBuilder`. I see you instantiate a `StringBuilder`. Then I see you converting its contents to a string and then to a byte array. However I don't see you putting anything into the `StringBuilder`

Comment: @Flydog57 It is probably a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  For what is being done here, the contents are irrelevant.

Comment: I disagree.  A [mre] would include something like `csvContent.AppendLine("Hello, World");`

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. I have Append Line but it was me extracting data from certain endpoints. I just edited my code to append a dummy line.

Comment: The code works fine. Are you sure you are linking to the correct url? And try removing `download ="Report.csv"` from the html.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the correct type on your controller, in this case a `FileResult`, your method should look like this:

```
public FileResult GenerateCSV()

   {
        StringBuilder csvContent = new StringBuilder();
        string fileName = "CSVTest.csv";
        byte[] csvData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvContent.ToString());


         //Send the File to Download.
         return File(csvData , "text/csv", "Report.csv");
   }
```

In this case you don't need the `download` tag in your `<a>`

```
<a href ="/MyAccount/GenerateCSV"  class="btn btn-primary">Generate &raquo;</a>
```

Comment: There is still nothing in the `StringBuilder` and so nothing in `csvData`, so nothing to download